# Magento 2 - Best way to check if the current category is child

Tags: magento2, php, layout, category, magento2.2

I want to change the design of my store depends of the categories and subcategories.

I need to check if the current category is subcategory and if is subcategory then display something there.

I made this before in Magento 1.9 with the getLevel function:

```
$isLevel3 = $_category->getLevel() == 3;
if ($isLevel3) {
```

how I can get the Level in Magento 2 version?

Thank you

**Edit:**

I get the subcategories level in Magento 2 like this:

```
$_category  = $block->getCurrentCategory();
         $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
         $categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setStore($store)
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1')
                ->addFieldToFilter('include_in_menu', '1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level',3);
        $last = count($categories);
        $_category  = $block->getCurrentCategory();
        foreach ($categories as $ficategory):
                if($ficategory->getLevel() == 3) {
                    $mydiv = "subcategory";
                } 
        endforeach;
```

But how I can check if the current category is Level 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$catLevel = $ficategory->getLevel(); //3
if($catLevel == 3) {
    Your need here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play a little bit around this:

```
public function __constructor(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->registry = $registry;
}

public function isCurentCategorySubCategory() {
    if ($request->getFullActionName() !== "catalog_category_view") {
        throw new \Exception('This is not category view page')
    }
    if ($registry->registry('current_category')->getLevel() === '3') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I believe you have to do something like that

Comment: Thank you, will help me a lot if you can give me an example without a module, I work in a small phtml file.

Comment: phtml - is view layer. You shouldn't put the logic there... For that purpose, you should use view model php class.

https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-12-viewmodels-in-magento-2